# Is there a way to sync and update files from OneDrive to WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, onedrive

I have a client who currently stores hundreds of files on OneDrive that they want linked to their new product catalog on their website (WordPress). Not only that but they want to be able to update those files and have the links remain connected to the newest version of the file on the website.

Currently the filenames are similar to this: product_name_instructions_2023-5-30_v1.pdf. As you might guess when they update the file the date or v# will change.

**Option 1: Use OneDrive (spoiler alert, won't work)**

My first thought was, just to change them to a generic filename (product_name_instructions.pdf with no dates or versions) and upload the new file with the same filename and the link would stay the same. Therefore the link from the website would never need to be changed. After researching this I found that every time you upload a file to OneDrive the link to it is changes because a new fileID is created and it doesn't matter if the filename is the same.

I have searched more and there seem to be ways to sync OneDrive files to WordPress but I think that the client would still have to update the link on the product page every time they make an update to a file.

**Option 2: Software to sync files via WordPress.**

Is there any way that the files can automatically be synced? Maybe keep the filename that same when uploaded to OneDrive and have software in WordPress that can scan the OneDrive folder for filenames and "date_modified" and update the link if it is newer than the current link's "date_modified". I imagine that this would take some serious custom programming but I just want to know if it could be done (or if it already has been done... hopefully).

**Option 3: Auto sync files in OneDrive with /uploads folder on webserver via FTP**

Of course, I can always add a folder to WP Uploads and give them FTP access to that folder and have them manually upload the files there. This would mean that after changing the files they would have to upload them to OneDrive *and* the server via FTP. They would like to keep their current system (only uploading to OneDrive) if possible. Is there a way to sync a the folder in /uploads with a specific folder in OneDrive via FTP so they update automatically (i.e. newly updated files from OneDrive automatically upload to the server)?

Comment: There are WordPress plugins available that enable you to sync and update files between OneDrive and WordPress. These plugins provide more seamless integration and can automate the process of importing and synchronizing files.

Some popular plugins for integrating OneDrive with WordPress include:  
``1. WP OneDrive
2. OneDrive Files to Media Library ``  
Try above plugins, these may help.